# my dyanamic fancybox is not working

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate> 
<a class="fancybox" href="<%#Eval("image")%>" data-fancybox-group="gallery">
  <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("image")%>' CssClass="img-responsive" runat="server"></asp:Image></a>  
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

it show the error at server like "The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later"